# How to work with binary data within SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql

I have a table with a column holding binary data (pdf). I would like to work with this data. In the moment I only can export this data to filesystem. I use this very basic PS-script to export binary data to file (one file per cell).

```
$Server = "Servername\Instance";        
$Database = "Databasename";            
$Dest = "Path to destination like D:\export\";             
$bufferSize = 8192;                      

# Select-Statement for name & blob            
# with filter.  

$Sql = "
   select 
       cast([some ID for the name] as varchar(255)) as ID,
       [binary data]
   from [dbo].[table]
   where [binary data] is not null";            

# Open ADO.NET Connection 
$con = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;            
$con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server;" +             
                    "Integrated Security=True;" +            
                    "Initial Catalog=$Database";            
$con.Open();  

# New Command and Reader 
$cmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $Sql, $con; 
$cmd.CommandTimeout = 120 
$rd = $cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

# Create a byte array for the stream. 
$out = [array]::CreateInstance('Byte', $bufferSize) 

# Looping through records 
While ($rd.Read()) 
{ 
  try 
 { 
#   Write-Output ("Exporting: {0}" -f $rd.GetString(0)); 
# New BinaryWriter 
$fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream ($Dest + $rd.GetString(0) + '.pdf'),     Create, Write; 
$bw = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter $fs; 

$start = 0; 
# Read first byte stream 
$received = $rd.GetBytes(1, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1); 
While ($received -gt 0) 
{ 
 $bw.Write($out, 0,      $received); 
 $bw.Flush(); 
 $start += $received; 
# Read next byte stream 
$received = $rd.GetBytes(1, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1); 
} 
$bw.Close(); 
$fs.Close(); 
} 
catch 
{ 
 Write-Output ($_.Exception.Message) 
} 
finally 
{ 
 $fs.Dispose();         
}
}  

# Closing & Disposing remaining objects 
$rd.Close(); 
$cmd.Dispose(); 
$con.Close();
```

I know that SQL-Server is a database system that is optimized for set-operation. So maybe a database is not the best thing to use when it is about to store binary data. But the data comes from another source so I don't have too much of a choice.

Is there any way to "work" with the data within SQL Server?

Comment: This is both too vague and too broad. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: This entirely depends on what *"work"* means in your context, but since you are dealing with Pdf documents, there's next to nothing you can do before things get too complicated.

Comment: Sorry, but the only requirement I know is that I have to analyze the data. I know this is very vague, but I don't have anything more specific. The only thing I can do by now  (within the database) is to see weather there is data or not. What is abourt R-in database? Or is it simply a bad idea to analyse binary data in the database? For example: Is there no simple way to read the metadata of the pdfs?

Comment: Until you know precisely what "analyze the data" means, there isn't much anyone else can offer. If you cannot do this manually by looking at your files, I don't see how you can write code to do it.

Comment: You need to write a software to read the PFDs from data base and a PDF library to parse the content. The only thing you can do in SQL Server is using PDF filter and use text search to search data. nothing more you can do AFAIK.

Comment: @FLICKER: Maybe text seach is a good option now (2012+). I did never get it really running in early versions. So maybe it is worth a try. There should be a lot of usefull things there - textmining is one of the marketing hypes, isn't it.

Comment: so you can add PDF filter to enable that.

Comment: @FLICKER: You need serveradmin role to start the fulltext_service. An errormessage claimed for that after a full population of my index. That is a pitty and unfortuanately an absolute no-go on production systems here.

Comment: @Christian4143, I don't get what you say. The service should be already started, you just need to use the feature in your queries.

Comment: Maybe already the population of the index didn't word. I don't know. A simple query like select * from table_with_index where freetext([NAME], 'Picasso') gives "Msg 30046, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
SQL Server encountered error 0x80070422 while communicating with full-text filter daemon host (FDHost) process. Make sure that the FDHost process is running. To re-start the FDHost process, run the sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts' command or restart the SQL Server instance."